# Using UniSwap smart contracts with Flutter

Tags: flutter, smartcontracts, uniswap

I'm currently want to interact with UniSwap Smart Contract v2 with web3dart to make a swap dapp in flutter? Anyone did this before?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wallet_connect package from pub.dev to connect to uniswap. If your goal is to connect to the dex from your dapp and let the dex interact with the contract (https://pub.dev/packages/wallet_connect)

```
final wcClient = WCClient(
      onConnect: () {
        // Respond to connect callback
      },
      onDisconnect: (code, reason) {
        // Respond to disconnect callback
      },
      onFailure: (error) {
        // Respond to connection failure callback
      },
      onSessionRequest: (id, peerMeta) {
        // Respond to connection request callback
      },
      onEthSign: (id, message) {
        // Respond to personal_sign or eth_sign or eth_signTypedData request callback
      },
      onEthSendTransaction: (id, tx) {
        // Respond to eth_sendTransaction request callback
      },
      onEthSignTransaction: (id, tx) {
        // Respond to eth_signTransaction request callback
      },
    );
```

Then write functions to respond to each functions as you want.

**To create your own dex**

If you want to directly access the UniSwap Smart Contract v2 without connecting to the dex, then you can use the **router02 contract** of uniswap to safely swap assets.

You need to first import the ABI of **router02** to your dapp, you can get the abi here,
https://unpkg.com/@uniswap/v2-periphery@1.1.0-beta.0/build/IUniswapV2Router02.json

Then implement the fucntions to interact with the smart contract. You can get the details here,
https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/reference/smart-contracts/router-02

Comment: I did successfully connect to Uniswap router v2 smart contract. But now i don't know how to use the swap functions to swap in metamask. Can you help?

Comment: And i use wallet_connect_dart package. This is the link https://pub.dev/packages/walletconnect_dart

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the idea to create a package with that feature and here it is, new features will be added over the next few weeks...

https://github.com/SantiiRepair/uniswap_dart

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).